# Textview will not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, textview

I have a view where the root view is a Scrollview.
The scrollview wraps a textview amongst other images etc.

When there is a large amount of text in the textview in order to scroll to the bottom I first have to make sure I have scrolled to the top of the view with the root scrollview, otherwise the the textview will not scroll.

It seems the root scrollview has focus if it has been scrolled and therefore tetview cannot scroll.

So my question - is this the way the textview and root scroll should interact and is there a way to allow focus on textview scroll without having to scroll back to the top of the main view using the root scroll?

Thanks In Advance